# Mount a Time Machine backup disk that will not mount

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, disk-utility, mount

I just plugged in my external hd via USB for a Time Machine backup. However it will not mount.

[image]

I've:

- Unplugged the hd
- Restarted the computer
- Plugged it back in

When I do this, Disk Utility spins and won't load. So I then:

- Unplug the disk
- Open Disk Utility
- Plug in the disk and that shows the image above

When I press mount, it says the disk is already unlocked. However it will not show up.

This started after I tried repairing the volume, but it wouldn't repair. Now I can't select it.

Any options at this point other than erasing the whole HD and starting over?

Comment: same problem here, did you find a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems like this also. If you have multiple USB ports try using a different port. Also try using a different cable and a different port.

You don't want to use a flaky drive for your backup. So, yes it seems like reformatting the drive and starting over makes sense, or replace it.

Answer (score 0):

The drive repair function in Disk Utility is and always has been mostly useless. If you really want to repair a drive (with software problems, not hardware problems of course), you need a program like Disk Warrior.